# Reset score from an objective?

Tags: java, bukkit

I have a big issue with removing a score from the scoreboard using Bukkit API. Here is my code:

```
ScoreBoard board;
Objective obj = board.registerNewObjective("foo", "dummy");
obj.getScore("bar").setScore(5);
// ...
```

Now, I need to remove that `"bar"` score from the scoreboard (objective). How do I do that? I did research, and couldn't find a method in the Bukkit API that would remove an existing score entry from the objective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Scoreboard.resetScores(String)`](https://github.com/Wolvereness/Bukkit-Bleeding/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/scoreboard/Scoreboard.java#L92-L98) if the entry for `"bar"` exists only in the objective and resetting the score will remain feasible (e.g. Not when another [`Objective`](https://github.com/Wolvereness/Bukkit-Bleeding/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/scoreboard/Objective.java) contains an entry):

```
{
    Objective obj;
    // ...
    obj.getScoreboard().resetScores("bar");
}
```

Otherwise, you can replace the objective, leaving out the item to remove:

```
{
    Objective obj;
    // ...
    Scoreboard sb = obj.getScoreboard();
    final HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String entry : sb.getEntries())
        map.put(entry, obj.getScore(entry).getScore();
    obj.unregister();
    obj = sb.registerNewObjective("foo", "dummy");
    for (final Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet())
        obj.getScore(entry.getKey()).setScore(entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the `resetScores()` method of the Scoreboard can help ([resetScores of Scoreboard](http://jd.bukkit.org/dev/doxygen/d1/dca/interfaceorg_1_1bukkit_1_1scoreboard_1_1Scoreboard.html#acf1a7312f41ef988d567e2cdeb8473c0))

Alternatively the `unregister()` method of the Objective can achieve your goal?
([unregister of Objective](http://jd.bukkit.org/dev/doxygen/db/dbc/interfaceorg_1_1bukkit_1_1scoreboard_1_1Objective.html#a8103b7b1bfc09573d77ece7cdb8204c4))

I believe the second method does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`Scoreboard.resetScores(String)`](http://jd.bukkit.org/dev/apidocs/org/bukkit/scoreboard/Scoreboard.html#resetScores(java.lang.String)).

> Removes all scores for an entry on this Scoreboard